# Correct way to send a boundary values in Headers php

Tags: php, http-headers

I was provided the following api to submit project updates that are either photos or text

```
POST  https://linktosite/api/projects/id/updates?limit=limit&offset=offset

Request 

User Authenticated

HEADERS
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=__BOUNDARY__

BODY

--__BOUNDARY__
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"

foo bar2
--__BOUNDARY__
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image"; filename="image.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0a
HBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIy
MjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCAABAAEDASIA
AhEBAxEB/8QAFQABAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAf/xAAUEAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/8QAFAEB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/EABQRAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AL+AD//Z
--__BOUNDARY__--
```

I'm looking for a curl-less solution if possible. This is what I have so far. It keeps returning a error and I don't know where I should pass the user authentication

```
$destination = "https://linktosite/api/projects/". $projectid ."/updates?limit=limit&offset=offset";

$eol = "\r\n";
$data = '';

$mime_boundary=md5(time());

$data .= '--' . $mime_boundary . $eol;
$data .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="message"' . $eol . $eol;
$data .= $_POST['message'] . $eol;
$data .= '--' . $mime_boundary . $eol;
$data .= 'Content-Disposition: form-data; name="image";   filename="image.jpg"' . $eol;
$data .= 'Content-Type: image/jpeg' . $eol;
$data .= 'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64' . $eol . $eol;
$data .= chunk_split(base64_encode(
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAgGBgcGBQgHBwcJCQgKDBQNDAsLDBkSEw8UHRofHh0a
HBwgJC4nICIsIxwcKDcpLDAxNDQ0Hyc5PTgyPC4zNDL/2wBDAQkJCQwLDBgNDRgyIRwhMjIyMjIy
MjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjIyMjL/wAARCAABAAEDASIA
AhEBAxEB/8QAFQABAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAf/xAAUEAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA/8QAFAEB
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/EABQRAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD/2gAMAwEAAhEDEQA/AL+AD//Z
)) . $eol;
$data .= "--" . $mime_boundary . "--" . $eol . $eol; // finish with two eol's!!

$params = array('http' => array(
                  'method' => 'POST',
                  'header' => 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=' . $mime_boundary . $eol,
                  'content' => $data
               ));

$ctx = stream_context_create($params);
$response = @file_get_contents($destination, FILE_TEXT, $ctx);
                                        print_r($response);
```

And this is my html form

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">  
    <input id="file-input" name="files" type="file"/>

    <input name="message" type="text" placeholder="Submit a update.."></input>  

    <input type="image" src="/img/arrows.png" border="0" alt="Submit" />                    
</form>
```

Comment: You're really using the wrong tools for the job. Try a proper HTTP client like the one in PEAR.

Comment: I was thinking of using Guzzle. Do you think PEAR's HTTP client is the better option?

Comment: Not sure, it's just what I've always used. [HTTP_Request2](https://pear.php.net/package/HTTP_Request2) is the current one. Never tried Guzzle.